# How to animate UI in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

```
  const animate_boxes = () => {
    inner_ref.current.style.transform = "scale(0)";
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (inner_ref && inner_ref.current) {
        inner_ref.current.style.transform = "scale(1)";
      }
    }, 200);
  };
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  animate_boxes();
}, [trigger])
```

Currently, that is how I do it.

Is is this the standard/good practice way?
If not, how can I re write the code above to simplify?

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent hooks based animation library called react-spring, you can use it by itself or alongside a gesture library to create nice, physics based animations that look natural. It has a bit of a learning curve though, [here's the library's website](https://react-spring.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can animate is by utilizing the CSS transition attribute with react state and inline styles:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-3t3p6?file=/Hello.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const blueSquare = {
  width: "25px",
  height: "25px",
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  transition: "opacity 0.5s, transform 3s",
  margin: 20
};

const Hello = () => {
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(1);
  const [transform, setTransform] = useState("translate(0,0) scale(1)");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTransform("translate(100px, 150px) scale(8)");
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTransform("translate(300px, 150px) scale(8)");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setOpacity((prevState) => (prevState === 1 ? 0 : 1))}
      >
        Animate Opacity
      </button>
      <div style={{ ...blueSquare, transform, opacity }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hello;
```

But as Brandon mentioned if you want to do complex animations it'd most likely be easier looking into react-spring.